# Getting java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError when use groovy @AnnotationCollector

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spock

I've written @Integration3Test annotation for spock tests. I use groovy @AnnotationCollector.
@Integration3Test is not used yet, just resides under the `groovy` directory.
When I build project I'm getting an exception. Project source code in `kotlin`.

```
./gradlew build
...

org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not execute test class 'com.lib.test.Integration3Test$CollectorHelper'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:53)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: com.lib.test.Integration3Test and com.lib.test.Integration3Test$CollectorHelper disagree on InnerClasses attribute
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1523)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.isInnerClass(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.access$200(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.execute(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.execute(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    ... 23 more
```

Here is mine annotation:

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = [Profiles.TEST])
@SpringBootTest(classes = [ServiceApplication])
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = [ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        SpringMockTestExecutionListener.class])
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = Options.DYNAMIC_PORT, stubs = "classpath:wiremock/mappings")
@EmbeddedKafka(controlledShutdown = true, partitions = 1)
@TestPropertySource(properties = ["spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=\${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}"])
@AnnotationCollector
public @interface Integration3Test {}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a minimal project reproducing the issue, here or on GitHub? I mean a full Gradle project. Your sample annotation does not even have a list of imports or dependencies needed for those imports. I also do not have a Kotlin sample project here, especially not for Gradle. I am also not sure if the annotation is implemented in Groovy as `@AnnotationCollector` and it residing in the `groovy` directory imply or if this is meant to be (or accidentally) compiled by a Kotlin compiler.

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem in my Maven playground project for Spock 2 and Groovy 3 and noticed that using Groovy-Eclipse-Batch compiler 3.0.6-01 failed to compile annotations with `@AnnotationCollector` if any of the participating annotations contained enum values such as `port = Options.DYNAMIC_PORT` or `profiles = [Profiles.TEST]`. After upgrading to Groovy 3.0.7 and Groove-Eclipse-Batch 3.0.7-02, compilation went well and a test annotated with `@Integration3Test` ran flawlessly. I never saw your type of callstack, though, which is why I need the MCVE.